# SQL LEFT JOIN not returning all expected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have seen multiple posts similar to my issue but none seem to solve my problem.

I am trying to get all months back for records even if they have a zero value for that supplier.  So as suggested in other posts, I created another table (view actually) that has all the months and year numbers.  Then used a LEFT JOIN on that view to try to get all the months.

I also learned from another post to move my WHERE condition to the join ON conditions. Still no joy.

Here is my query but I do not receive all 12 months for each supplier, only the ones with records for that month.

```
SELECT  
    Supplier, [Supplier Name],
    m.[MonthNum Received] AS MonthNum,
    m.[Year Received] AS [Year],
    COUNT(OTD) AS [All], SUM(CASE WHEN s.OTD = 'Early' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Early,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.OTD = 'Ontime' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OnTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.OTD = 'Late' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Late,
    SUM([Receipt Quantity]) AS Qty,
    CAST(100 - CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN s.OTD = 'Late' THEN 1 WHEN s.OTD = 'Early' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(18, 0)) / COUNT(OTD) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18, 0)) AS [Percent]
FROM    
    [v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months] m 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.[v_DA006-RECEIPTS] AS s ON m.[MonthNum Received] = s.[MonthNum Received] 
                                  AND m.[Year Received] = s.[Year Received] 
                                  AND (s.[Receipt Quantity] <> 0)
GROUP BY 
    Supplier, [Supplier Name], m.[MonthNum Received], m.[Year Received]
```

Comment: Does `[v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months]` have records for all 12 months in it for each supplier?

Comment: You have to join to a table, artificial or otherwise, that contains all months.

Comment: If you want the zero records why are you chopping them out with AND (s.[Receipt Quantity] <> 0)

Comment: This seems strange. Are you 100% sure that your [v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months]-view contains all the months? Have you tried to simply write `SELECT * FROM [v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months]`. Whenever you do a left join like this, the database engine should return all records from the left table, since you don't have any WHERE-criteria. The grouping doesn't matter.

Comment: [v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months]  has all months, I am certain.

Comment: The reason for the <>0 was because there were records being returned in the original table that have 0 line items received.  they had to be excluded.  I guess that can probably be removed, I removed that and results do not change.

Comment: Yes, I can verify I do a SELECT * FROM [v_DA006-RECEIPTS_Months] and get back all the months, year for 2014.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the suppliers. If there's no Suppliers table you should extract them from your transactions, then join with the months you want to report and finally left join with the transactions.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Suppliers a
     CROSS JOIN Months b
     LEFT JOIN Transactions c 
       ON a.Supplier = c.Supplier 
       AND b.year = c.year
       AND b.month = c.month
WHERE ...
```

this should give you at least one row for each supplier, year, month, eventually with null values in Transactions. then you can group by and summarize.

Comment: This solution has me real close...  I am getting all suppliers with a record for all months, but the months that do not have transactions for that supplier have NULL for the monthnum and yearnum.  How do I get those values to populate?

Comment: those NULLs mean that there is no transaction that matches. the month and year are available from table Months.

Comment: Understood on the comment about why the NULLs are there, but not sure how to force the monthnum and yearnum to appear anyway for the results.  For the transactions, I am changing to 0 from null.

Comment: SELECT [bp_supplier_name]
      ,[bp_supplier_number]
   ,ISNULL(c.[All],0) AS [All]
   ,c.[MonthNum]
   ,c.[YearNum]
  FROM [Workflow].[dbo].[v_SupplierScorecard_SupplierList] a
  CROSS JOIN [v_DA006-ReceiptMonthNumbers] b
   LEFT JOIN v_ScoreCard_SUM c
  ON a.bp_supplier_name=c.[Supplier Name]
  AND b.[Year Received]=c.[YearNum]
  AND b.[MonthNum Received]=c.[MonthNum]

Comment: The table v_DA006-ReceiptMonthNumbers returns a list of all months 1-12 and the year 2014

Comment: use b.YearReceived and b.MonthNum